# Accessing Gridview Template field from Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im having a problem for days. Here is my situation:

I have a `Gridview Template` field which is a `ImageButton`. When the `ImageButton` is clicked, A modal `pop up Panel` opens. Inside my panel is a button for cancel.

What I want is When the user clicks the cancel button. I will set my

```
ImageButton.Visible = true;
```

But I can't seem to do that because of this error

*`Unable to cast object of type WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder to type WebControls.GridViewRow`*

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    GridViewRow GridViewRow = (GridViewRow)button.NamingContainer;
    GridViewRow.FindControl("stopImageButton").Visible = true;
    this.StopTimeNotesPanel_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I guess the method to define a ItemTemplate may not be technically correct.Please follow the simple structure defined by MSDN it will solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx